# Why my counter function from jquery didnt work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

Hello so i'm trying to make counter for my website and i'm not that good at javascript so i think i have some error on my javascript, can you guys help me write some code that will work please ? thanks before.

Here's my head code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
```

My html code:

```
 <div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-up">
      <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-lg 3">
          <div class="counter">724</div>
          <div class="text">Working hours</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="counter">1200</div>
          <div class="text">Projects</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="counter">3123</div>
          <div class="text">Happy Client </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="counter">992</div>
          <div class="text">Flower</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".counter").counterUp({
        delay: 10,
        time: 120
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected, But to see the animation I've changed the `delay` from `10` to `1`

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".counter").counterUp({
        delay: 1,
        time: 120
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>

 <div class="container-fluid padding text-center counter-up">
      <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-lg 3">
          <div class="counter">724</div>
          <div class="text">Working hours</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="counter">1200</div>
          <div class="text">Projects</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="counter">3123</div>
          <div class="text">Happy Client </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="counter">992</div>
          <div class="text">Flower</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, so i tried to separate the javascript from the html, resulting this error 
script.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at script.js:1

Comment: This may be because jquery is not properly included. Check again

Comment: For some reason if i didn't separate the java script it will work. But if i try to scroll down below and then get back to the counter part, it will only count up to half of the value I want. for example i set it to 700 but it will only count up to 370

And if i try to separate it to script.js it will show some error.

Comment: No one can help you with the code that you've formentioned. It would be better to add some more code or add some reference to codepen or codesandbox. So that everyone can understand problem properly and help you.